# how connect myProject to mainProject on github (Android Studio)

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab, telegram

in the past, I did not download the telegram source with the git but now i need update my source and I need connect myProject (my Unofficial Telegram), to mainProject ([Telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)) on github. my IDE is Android Studio. git in Android Studio is in VCS menu. but I do not know what to do, for conect my project to github project.

Comment: you can clone telegram from source and put `.git` folder in your project .... then run a `pull` command

Comment: This will help you on how it's done. https://gist.github.com/CristinaSolana/1885435

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have git installed on your system. If not, go to this link and download it
  https://git-scm.com/download/win
- Right click inside your local project folder and select 'Git Bash Here'
- (If you want to clone your entire GitHub project into your local project, do it by typing:

  `git clone https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram.git`

  If you already have the files and you just want to update it, skip this cloning step)
- Check if your project folder has .git folder in it. (Check the hidden folders too) If there isn't one, type the following in your GitBash window

  `git init`
- Add the link to your GitHub (remote origin)  by typing

  `git remote add origin https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram.git`
- Update your files with the GitHub source by typing

  `git pull origin master`

If you just want to know how to connect your project in Android Studio to GitHub, here's a simple tutorial:
https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/
(Skip the steps where he creates a new GitHub repository and an Android Studio project, since you already have both)

For detailed understanding on using git and github, i suggest you take this course:
https://in.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775